# Export Power-shell result with Multiple Output into Single Email

Tags: sql-server, powershell, outlook

I am running this simple Powershell script to fetch SQL Server services status,drive status, db status and Job status. I know I can use Out-file but I need all the results in one email body. Below is my script and the result

```
    $DestInstance = "servername"
    $DestDatabase = "master"
    $smtpServer = "forwarder.mail.xerox.com"
    $supportContact = "Andleeb.Hasan@xerox.com"


  $O1  = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $DestInstance | Where-Object {$_.Displayname -in "SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)","SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER)"} | Format-Table -Property Displayname, state -AutoSize

    
    $O2=
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DriveType = '3'" | 
Select-Object -Property DeviceID, VolumeName,
@{L="Capacity";E={"{0:N2}" -f ($_.Size/1GB)}}, 
@{L='FreeSpaceGB';E={"{0:N2}" -f ($_.FreeSpace /1GB)}},
@{L='FreeSpacePerCent';E={"{0:N2}" -f (100*$_.FreeSpace /$_.size)}}|Format-table -Autosize


$O3=
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database $DestDatabase -ServerInstance "$DestInstance" -Query "SELECT name as Database_Name, state_desc as Database_Status
FROM   sys.databases where name in ('Core01_Prod',
'EquipmentCatalogue',
'iL_Exposure_PRODUCTION',
'iL_Exposure_STAGING',
'LookUpTables',
'ReportServer',
'ReportServerTempDB'
) order by name" |Format-table -Autosize

$O4=
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database $DestDatabase -ServerInstance "$DestInstance" -Query ";WITH CTE_MostRecentJobRun AS 
 ( 
 -- For each job get the most recent run (this will be the one where Rnk=1) 
 SELECT job_id,run_status,run_date,run_time 
 ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY job_id ORDER BY run_date DESC,run_time DESC) AS Rnk 
 FROM MSDB.dbo.sysjobhistory 
 WHERE step_id=0 
 ) 
SELECT  
  name  AS [Job Name]
 ,CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(S,(run_time/10000)*60*60 /* hours */ 
  +((run_time - (run_time/10000) * 10000)/100) * 60 /* mins */ 
  + (run_time - (run_time/100) * 100)  /* secs */, 
  CONVERT(DATETIME,RTRIM(run_date),113)),100) AS [Last Run]
 ,CASE WHEN enabled=1 THEN 'Enabled' 
     ELSE 'Disabled' 
  END [Job Status]
FROM     CTE_MostRecentJobRun MRJR 
JOIN     MSDB.dbo.sysjobs SJ 
ON       MRJR.job_id=sj.job_id 
WHERE    Rnk=1 
AND      run_status=1 -- 
ORDER BY [Last Run] desc " | Format-table -Autosize
```

**The Output of this scripts looks like this :**

```
Displayname                    state  
-----------                    -----  
SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)       Running
SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER) Running



DeviceID VolumeName Capacity FreeSpaceGB FreeSpacePerCent
-------- ---------- -------- ----------- ----------------
C:       OS         80.00    16.62       20.77           
D:       Logs-D     300.01   288.04      96.01           
E:       TempDB-E   40.00    5.23        13.07           
F:       Database-F 1,000.06 206.31      20.63           
G:       SnapInfo   349.92   212.48      60.72           
H:       Backup-H   800.16   521.45      65.17           
I:       SystemDB-I 9.97     4.06        40.69           



Database_Name          Database_Status
-------------          ---------------
Core01_Prod            ONLINE         
EquipmentCatalogue     ONLINE         
iL_Exposure_PRODUCTION ONLINE         
iL_Exposure_STAGING    ONLINE         
LookUpTables           ONLINE         
ReportServer           ONLINE         
ReportServerTempDB     ONLINE         



PS C:\PS> C:\PS\Server_Info.ps1

Displayname                    state  
-----------                    -----  
SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)       Running
SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER) Running



DeviceID VolumeName Capacity FreeSpaceGB FreeSpacePerCent
-------- ---------- -------- ----------- ----------------
C:       OS         80.00    16.62       20.77           
D:       Logs-D     300.01   288.04      96.01           
E:       TempDB-E   40.00    5.23        13.07           
F:       Database-F 1,000.06 206.31      20.63           
G:       SnapInfo   349.92   212.48      60.72           
H:       Backup-H   800.16   521.45      65.17           
I:       SystemDB-I 9.97     4.06        40.69           



Database_Name          Database_Status
-------------          ---------------
Core01_Prod            ONLINE         
EquipmentCatalogue     ONLINE         
iL_Exposure_PRODUCTION ONLINE         
iL_Exposure_STAGING    ONLINE         
LookUpTables           ONLINE         
ReportServer           ONLINE         
ReportServerTempDB     ONLINE         



PS C:\PS> C:\PS\Server_Info.ps1

Displayname                    state  
-----------                    -----  
SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)       Running
SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER) Running



DeviceID VolumeName Capacity FreeSpaceGB FreeSpacePerCent
-------- ---------- -------- ----------- ----------------
C:       OS         80.00    16.62       20.77           
D:       Logs-D     300.01   288.04      96.01           
E:       TempDB-E   40.00    5.23        13.07           
F:       Database-F 1,000.06 206.31      20.63           
G:       SnapInfo   349.92   212.48      60.72           
H:       Backup-H   800.16   521.45      65.17           
I:       SystemDB-I 9.97     4.06        40.69           



Database_Name          Database_Status
-------------          ---------------
Core01_Prod            ONLINE         
EquipmentCatalogue     ONLINE         
iL_Exposure_PRODUCTION ONLINE         
iL_Exposure_STAGING    ONLINE         
LookUpTables           ONLINE         
ReportServer           ONLINE         
ReportServerTempDB     ONLINE         



Job Name                                   Last Run            Job Status
--------                                   --------            ----------
Rapport Logon History Purge - Core01_Prod  Sep 23 2021 12:30AM Enabled   
Bring iLease Databases Online              Sep 23 2021 12:20AM Enabled   
Take iLease Databases Offline              Sep 23 2021 12:00AM Enabled   
Rapport Session Timeout - Core01_Prod      Sep 23 2021 10:34AM Enabled   
Rapport Match Criteria Purge - Core01_Prod Sep 23 2021 10:30AM Enabled   
Xerox Legacy Data Update                   Sep 23 2021  2:00AM Enabled   
syspolicy_purge_history                    Sep 23 2021  2:00AM Enabled   
AgentJob_PopulateCurrentExposure           Sep 22 2021  6:00PM Enabled   
Shrink Core01_Prod Log Files               Sep 19 2021 11:30AM Enabled   
MaintenancePlan.Subplan_1                  Sep 19 2021  1:30AM Enabled
```

**How can I email the whole output in one single email? I am unable to bring all the results in One email using Out-file**

Comment: Why would you be unable to do that using Out-File? You could simply use a variable to save your output and use that instead of having it directly displayed. This will have other issues but is an option to easily collect what you need to send.

Comment: @Seth - Yes I am not using Out-file now. I am trying to get the Output this way.

 `$smtpServer = "test.test1.com"
    $supportContact = "testuser@xerox.com"
$Output=$O1+$O2+$O3+$O4
$Now = Get-Date -uformat "%a %d %b %Y"
Send-MailMessage -To $supportContact -From "test@test.com" -Subject "Test SUbject" -Body "$Output" -SmtpServer "$smtpServer" -BodyAsHtml -Priority High`

But i am still not getting the correct Output in email.. could you help me correct this please?

Comment: Well what's incorrect about it? Depending on how those objects behave you might have to run Out-String separately.

Comment: I am getting this in email Output
`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData `

Answer (score 2):

I resolved it by updating code as belows :

```
    $DestInstance = "servername"
    $DestDatabase = "master"
    $smtpServer = "x.y.z.com"
    $supportContact = "testuser@test.com"


  $O1  = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $DestInstance | Where-Object {$_.Displayname -in "SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)","SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER)"}

    
    $O2=
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DriveType = '3'" | 
Select-Object -Property DeviceID, VolumeName,
@{L="Capacity";E={"{0:N2}" -f ($_.Size/1GB)}}, 
@{L='FreeSpaceGB';E={"{0:N2}" -f ($_.FreeSpace /1GB)}},
@{L='FreeSpacePerCent';E={"{0:N2}" -f (100*$_.FreeSpace /$_.size)}}


$O3=
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database $DestDatabase -ServerInstance "$DestInstance" -Query "SELECT name as Database_Name, state_desc as Database_Status
FROM   sys.databases where name in ('Core01_Prod',
'EquipmentCatalogue',
'iL_Exposure_PRODUCTION',
'iL_Exposure_STAGING',
'LookUpTables',
'ReportServer',
'ReportServerTempDB'
) order by name" 

$O4=
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database $DestDatabase -ServerInstance "$DestInstance" -Query ";WITH CTE_MostRecentJobRun AS 
 ( 
 -- For each job get the most recent run (this will be the one where Rnk=1) 
 SELECT job_id,run_status,run_date,run_time 
 ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY job_id ORDER BY run_date DESC,run_time DESC) AS Rnk 
 FROM MSDB.dbo.sysjobhistory 
 WHERE step_id=0 
 ) 
SELECT  
  name  AS [Job Name]
 ,CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(S,(run_time/10000)*60*60 /* hours */ 
  +((run_time - (run_time/10000) * 10000)/100) * 60 /* mins */ 
  + (run_time - (run_time/100) * 100)  /* secs */, 
  CONVERT(DATETIME,RTRIM(run_date),113)),100) AS [Last Run]
 ,CASE WHEN enabled=1 THEN 'Enabled' 
     ELSE 'Disabled' 
  END [Job Status]
FROM     CTE_MostRecentJobRun MRJR 
JOIN     MSDB.dbo.sysjobs SJ 
ON       MRJR.job_id=sj.job_id 
WHERE    Rnk=1 
AND      run_status=1 -- 
ORDER BY [Last Run] desc " 





$style = "<style>BODY{font-family: Ariel, font-size: 12pt;}"
          $style = $style + "TABLE{border: 1px solid Green; border-collapse: collapse;}"
          $style = $style + "TH{border: 1px solid Red; background: #dddddd; padding: 5px;}"
          $style = $style + "TD{border: 1px solid Red; padding: 5px;}"
          $style = $style + "</style>"
          $b1 = ($O1 | Select-Object -Property Displayname, State | ConvertTo-HTML -Head $style)
          $b2 = ($O2 | Select-Object -Property DeviceID,VolumeName,Capacity,FreeSpaceGB,FreeSpacePerCent | ConvertTo-HTML -Head $style)
          $b3 = ($O3 | Select-Object -Property 'Database_Name','Database_Status' | ConvertTo-HTML -Head $style)
          $b4 = ($O4 | Select-Object -Property 'Job Name','Last Run','Job Status' | ConvertTo-HTML -Head $style)
          $Now = Get-Date -uformat "%a %d %b %Y"
#$O=($b | ConvertTo-HTML -Head $style | Out-String )
Send-MailMessage -To $supportContact -From "test@test.com" -Subject "Test Subject" -Body "$b1$b2$b3$b4" -SmtpServer "$smtpServer" -BodyAsHtml -Priority High
```

Comment: Please consider marking your answer as the solution to your question.

Comment: I think i can mark it after two days...i 'll do it..Thanks